# Multiple fragments in one Activity which download data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Here's what I want:

FragmentActivity first shows Fragment1, then Fragment2.
Each one of the Fragments should:

- show custom progress dialog before downloading data
- download data from Internet
- dismiss dialog
- populate views with fetched data

I have FragmentActivity and child Fragments call activity method when new Fragment should be shown:

```
public class ActivityInTab extends FragmentActivity {
    public void navigateTo(Fragment newFragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, newFragment);

        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

If I used Activities instead of fragment I'd write something like that:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStage){
        super.onCreate();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        showDialog();//Show ProgressDialog here
        startFetchingData();
    }

    private void startFetchingData(){
        new DownloadDataTask().execute(...);
    }

    private class DownloadDataTask extends AsynkTask<...>{
        protected void onPostExecute(...){
            populateViewsWithDownloadedData();
            hideDialog();//dismiss ProgressDialog
        }
    }
}
```

Which Fragment lifecycle callbacks should I use for this steps?

Comment: Did you tried implementing something and failed?

Comment: @Luksprog I guess my question is quite straightforward, It's not like, "hey, guys, my app is not working". I have problem determining which lifecycle callbacks should be used for specific operations.

Comment: Your question is not so straightforward as you may think. Do you want to start the `ProgressDialog`(when should this happen?) from the `Activity` for each of the fragments or do you want that each fragment show its own dialog when its visible? How do you switch from one fragment to another fragment? Populate views from where, fragment/ activity/ both?

Comment: @Luksprog thanks for your comment! I edited my answer and I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Well you only need one of the lifecycle methods, for example `onActivityCreated`. In that method you could show the dialog(or even better, incorporate it in the `AsyncTask` in the onPre/PostExecute callbacks) and start the task to download stuff. When the task finishes update the views of the fragment.